# Bcrypt - Automatizando processo de encryptação de senhas

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá. já tenho uma coluna no meu banco chamada password. Uso devise para autenticação, então ele criou uma outra coluna chamada encypted_password. Mesmo que eu copie todos os valores de password e jogue para encrypted_password, eu daria de cara com um erro, já que as senhas nao foram criptografas. Há algum modo de fazer com que já no momento da cópia, os valores de password fossem criptografados belo bcrypt e jogados na coluna de destino? Sem algo assim, teria que fazer tudo na mão, um por um.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma solução, um pouco antiga, para isso. Você pode deixar o devise fazer isso por você. Essa solução [vem deste gist](https://gist.github.com/moeffju/1704632).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?

  def valid_password?(password)
    begin
      devise_valid_password?(password)
    rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
      return false unless Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password) == encrypted_password
      logger.info "User #{email} is using the old password hashing method, updating attribute."
      self.password = password
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Isso irá converter as senhas para o padrão do devise. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mesma pergunta feita no stack overflow gringo, pode ser útil para ver as diversas respostas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113375/converting-existing-password-hash-to-devise